# Rename file with contents of file

Tags: bash, newlines, tr

So I've [downloaded a bunch of text files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/637138/bash-brace-extension-for-2-identical-ranges) and want to rename these files to the title *that is contained within in those files*.

The output of `head sn-800.txt` is:

```
GIBSON RESEARCH CORPORATION             https://www.GRC.com/

SERIES:         Security Now!
EPISODE:        #800
DATE:           January 5, 2021
TITLE:          SolarBlizzard
HOSTS:  Steve Gibson & Leo Laporte
SOURCE: https://media.grc.com/sn/sn-800.mp3
ARCHIVE:        https://www.grc.com/securitynow.htm
```

In a nutshell, `sn-800.txt` should become `sn-800 - SolarBlizzard.txt`

Before I'm going to `mv` 335 files, I'm echoing everything on screen:

```
#!/bin/bash
for iEpisode in {802..807}; 
do 
  echo -n "sn-$iEpisode - ";
  grep "^TITLE:" sn-"$iEpisode".txt | 
  cut -d":" -f2 | 
  sed 's/\t//g' | 
  tr -d '\n';  
  echo ".txt";  
done
```

but can't seem to figure out how to remove the newline at the end (the `tr in the above) because that gives me:

```
.txt02 - Where the Plaintext Is
.txt03 - Comparative Smartphone Security
.txt04 - NAT Slipstreaming 2.0
.txt05 - SCADA Scandal
.txt06 - C.O.M.B.
sn-807 - Dependency Confusion.txt
```

For some or other reason the last file is correct, but the files before still have a newline somewhere??? (If I do a `-n` on the last `echo`, all file names are concatenated to one string)

*What am I doing wrong???*

Comment: Hint: use `grep -m1` to you don't search the whole file every time.

Comment: @FelixJN Thanks for that!  Faster now!  **:-)**

Comment: Another hint: `echo "sn-$iEpisode - $(grep -oP '^TITLE:\s*\K.*' sn-"$iEpisode".txt).txt"` should give you the file name in a single operation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The files have CR/LF line endings, so you need to delete `\r` too:

```
...
tr -d '\r\n';
...
```

This is the reason why `.txt` appears at the beginning of every line — it’s output at the end, but after the cursor has gone back to the beginning of the line.